# User impersonation in WCF message inspector

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

I'm facing a problem while using WCF message inspectors, the problem is I can't get the impersonated user in message inspector and when I try to get current user with WindowIdentity.GetCurrent() it returns AppPool\DefaultAppPool instead of impersonated user.

**On the other hand** if I try to get the user in OperationContract the impersonated user is available.

```
private void RequestValidationStart(ref Message request)
{
    // WindowIdentity.GetCurrent() returns IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool
    // instead of impersonated user
    var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowIdentity.GetCurrent();
}
```

How to get the impersonated user in WCF Message Inspector?

**Update:**

Rajesh requested me a service binding and authentication mechanism,this is how I configured my service:

```
<service name="MyEndPoint">
    <endpoin behaviorConfiguration="MyEndPointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="WebHttp"
    contract="MyEndPointContract"></endpoint>
</service>

<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WebHttp">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCertificateTrype="Basic"></transport>
        </security>
    </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Can you post on how your service/bindings look and what kind of authentication mechanism you have configured?

Comment: @Rajesh I updated my question and I provided what you asked me for.

Comment: @Ali.B Did you find a solution to this problem?